# How to solve binary labeling with graph cut?

Tags: c++, algorithm, graph

[image]

I have 32 segments of the overlapped regions of two images. I have to assign each of the segment to either one of the images based on lowest cost. So, it is a binary labeling problem, and above are the energy minimization function.

L is the vector of length of 32(equal to the number of segments) and value of each element depends on its index corresponding to the segment number. Say, if 3rd segment is assigned image 1, then L(2)=0, and 14th segments is assigned to image 2, so L(13)=1. That is L[x]'s value is either 0 or 1. Thus, there are 2^32 possible assignment of L. So, I can compute E(L) for each combination, after performing 2^32 calculation, I can get the minimum E(L), and use that combination. This is what my intuition suggests. But this is impractical, because the complexity is exponential.

But, many literatures suggest this binary labeling problem can be solved as a graph cut problem with max flow/min cut algorithm. But, how do I formulate this problem as max flow/min cut problem? The 32 segments are the nodes of the graph, but what would be the weight of the edges? And what would be the capacity?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The formulation as a graph theory problem and proof of the "if and only if" relationship can be found in ["What Energy Functions Can Be Minimized
via Graph Cuts?" by Vladimir Kolmogorov and Ramin Zabih](http://www.cs.cornell.edu/~rdz/Papers/KZ-PAMI04.pdf).

The key idea is to construct a directed edge between i and j of weight Vij(0,1)+Vij(1,0)-Vij(0,0)-Vij(1,1).

If Vij(1,0)-Vij(0,0)>0 you also need to construct a directed edge between the source and i of weight Vij(1,0)-Vij(0,0).
Otherwise you need to construct a directed edge between i and the destination of weight Vij(0,0)-Vij(1,0).

Similarly, if Vij(0,1)-Vij(0,0)>0 you also need to construct a directed edge between the source and j of weight Vij(0,1)-Vij(0,0).
Otherwise you need to construct a directed edge between j and the destination of weight Vij(0,0)-Vij(0,1).

Note that the min-cut of this graph will be offset by V(0,0)-sum of weights on edges connecting to the destination.